# What library do I need to link to use std::list in clang++?

Tags: c++, list, linker, clang, std

I am trying to use the `std::list` class in C++, and I need to use `clang++` to compile the program. g++ compiles the following program just fine, but I can't figure out how to compile/link it with clang++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main(){
  std::list<int> L;

  L.push_back(10);

  std::cout << L.back() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I've tried `clang++ -lstdc++ listTest.cpp` but still get the following error:

```
/tmp/listTest-3175a9.o: In function `std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert(std::_List_iterator<int>, int const&)':
listTest.cpp:(.text._ZNSt4listIiSaIiEE9_M_insertESt14_List_iteratorIiERKi[_ZNSt4listIiSaIiEE9_M_insertESt14_List_iteratorIiERKi]+0x31): undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Clang version:

```
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
```

linux version:

```
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

Comment: BTW `std::list` is not a class.

Comment: what do you mean it is not a class?

Comment: It's a class template

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @BrianVandenberg I did not resolve it on my specific system; it seems that `clang` was probably installed incorrectly, but I don't control the install so I could not fix it. Migrated to g++ for that particular project and it worked out okay.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide library arguments *after* the translation unit that uses them:

```
clang++ listTest.cpp -lstdc++
```

I should note that I couldn't reproduce your issue, but that could easily be down to differences in version/configuration (particularly w.r.t. a stdlib implementation selected for use by default).

Comment: Ah -- thank you. I flipped the order, and it still doesn't work, but if you can't reproduce the issue, then my guess is that something is wrong with the configuration on my system.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it on mine (redhat, clang 3.4, gcc 4.7.2).

By default this project was linking against `/usr/lib/libstdc++`.  I have a build of gcc 4.7.2 installed in a separate location; when I add lines analogous to the following to the link step it works fine

```
-L${GCC_PATH}/lib -Wl,-R${GCC_PATH}/lib
```

... provided they appear in the link step before analogous statements for `/usr/lib`.

---

*edit*

You can use `strace` to help diagnose this problem; I did something like the following:

```
// copy the link step into a temp shell script
strace -f ./temp.sh |& grep -P 'lib(std)?c\+\+'
```

... which is when I realized I probably needed a different build of the C++ runtime because I saw it was finding and linking against the one in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Hmm -- interesting. I can't seem to link properly to that library myself, but I'll do a bit more digging.